# What happens to a mint account secret key after an NFT is created?

Tags: nft, token, keypair

When you create a new traditional NFT, people generate a random keypair that gets used as the mint. This key signs the transaction so the account gets allocated on chain.

- Does the secret key for this keypair matter anymore?
- Can it be used for anything?
- Could it be share publicly without any real security issues?

If that same NFT was burned, the account closed and rent reclaimed, it would eventually be garbage collected. If you still had the original keypair, could you recreate something at that address (like a different NFT or even a program)?